# function not getting called in javascript. bundled by WebPack

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

I am facing an issue with JS function. I am able to open search bar but when i try to close it. The code is not getting triggered (**My first event is getting called but anything after that is not getting called/triggered**)

I am using WebPack which bundle the javascript into one bundle.js file

The code

html file

```
<div class="search-overlay">
    <div class="search-overlay__top">
      <div class="container">
          <i class="fa fa-search search-overlay__icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input type="text" name="" class="search-term " id="" placeholder="What are you looking for">
          <i class="fa fa-window-close search-overlay__icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js file

```
import $ from 'jquery';


class Search {
   constructor() {
        this.openScreen = $(".js-search-trigger"); 
        this.closeScreen = $(".search__close"); 
        this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay"); 
        this.events();
    }

    // 2. Events
    events() {
        this.openScreen.on("click", this.openOverlay.bind(this));
        this.closeScreen.on("click", this.closeOverlay.bind(this));
    }

     // 3. Methods
     openOverlay() {
         this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");
         $("body").addClass("body-no-scroll");
    }

    closeOverlay(){
        this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
        $("body").removeClass("body-no-scroll");
    }
  }

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your code the error was the timing, probably you are doing that to fast.

What I mean is, when you call to close de overlay, i'll probably does not have the class yet.

Another theory is that you have more than one `.search-overlay` on the scream and the `removeClass` function was trying to remove a class from another element.

Try to execute the selector on console to see how much elements you select with this selector. Then, try to execute your code, step by step, on console too.

Comment: I have inspected the element and do see the class being added..

Comment: and also have added a console.log to both the methods openoverlay and close overlay. and I see only  openOverlay method and one log being called.

Comment: But if you go to the dev console, wait the overlay opens on the screen and execute this line, it closes? `$(".search-overlay").removeClass("search-overlay--active");`

Comment: If it does not close, the class was removed?